# JSON containing quotes is not parsed correctly by JSON.load in my spec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec

I have this RSpec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

require 'integrations/youtube'

RSpec.describe YoutubeIntegration do

  let(:empty_playlist) {
  <<-JSON
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"",
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": []
  }
  JSON
  }

  context '- Auxiliary methods -' do

  end

  context '- Endpoint calls -' do

    it 'get_playlist_data' do
      obj = YoutubeIntegration.new
      response = obj.call('youtube','get_playlist_data',nil,:playlistId => "PL3umUDtI6E97kwmnzth_kMnOD0fkwJtuB")
      myjson = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(myjson).to eq JSON.load(empty_playlist)
    end

  end

end
```

It happens that Youtube Data API really returns `etag` this way, with quotes inside, as you may see [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it).

But when I run this spec I got this error

[image]

a parse error for unexpected token. I tested this JSON at [http://jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and it is fine, but `JSON#load` won't parse it.

On the other hand, if I take the inner quotes out and do just this:

```
  let(:empty_playlist) {
  <<-JSON
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo",
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": []
  }
  JSON
  }
```

Then I get this error

[image]

because now, of course, the content of `etag` is different from the expectation.

How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with the format of the `empty_playlist` you could represent it by a Hash... not a raw string...

then you could use

```
let(:empty_playlist) do
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"",
    "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": []
  }
end

context '- Auxiliary methods -' do

end

context '- Endpoint calls -' do

  it 'get_playlist_data' do
    obj = YoutubeIntegration.new
    response = obj.call('youtube','get_playlist_data',nil,:playlistId => "PL3umUDtI6E97kwmnzth_kMnOD0fkwJtuB")
    myjson = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(myjson).to eq empty_playlist
  end

end
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but please edit it for future reference of others. Instead of `expect(myjson).to eq empty_playlist.as_json` it is just `expect(myjson).to eq empty_playlist`. Since we are declaring a hash object, we don't need to convert it to JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that heredoc uses double quotes to allow for interpolation. This causes your `empty_playlist` string to actually look like:

```
" {
    \"kind\": \"youtube#playlistItemListResponse\",
    \"etag\": \"\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"\",
   \"pageInfo\": {
         \"totalResults\": 0,
         \"resultsPerPage\": 5
   },
   \"items\": []
  }"
```

notice the extra escaping around the etag value .

you could just use single quotes or you could double escape the quotes e.g

```
let(:empty_playlist) {
  '{
     "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
     "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"",
     "pageInfo": {
     "totalResults": 0,
     "resultsPerPage": 5
   },
   "items": []
  }'
}
```

OR

```
let(:empty_playlist) {
  <<-JSON
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
      "etag": "\\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\\"",
      "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
      },
      "items": []
    }
  JSON
}
```

Either one of these will load correctly with `JSON::load`